# "HttpDeleteWithBody" isn't deleted from Database

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to call to my `API` sending a `JSON` to ***delete*** a product from my DB; *however, it doesn't delete anything.*

*The response of the `JSON` is "true," and it doesn't give to me any error; even so, when I make a query on my DB, the product is still there.*

I've created a class called `HttpDeleteWithBody` that looks like:

```
class HttpDeleteWithBody extends HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase {
    public static final String METHOD_NAME = "DELETE";
    public String getMethod() { return METHOD_NAME; }

    public HttpDeleteWithBody(final String uri) {
        super();
        setURI(URI.create(uri));
    }
    public HttpDeleteWithBody(final URI uri) {
        super();
        setURI(uri);
    }
    public HttpDeleteWithBody() { super(); }
}
```

And then on my `doInBackGround` of my `Fragment`, I do this:

```
boolean resul = true;
try {
    JSONObject usuari = new JSONObject();
    try {
        usuari.put("idProducte", params[0]);
        usuari.put("idusuari", params[1]);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(usuari.toString());
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpDeleteWithBody httpDeleteWithBody = new HttpDeleteWithBody(getResources().getString(R.string.IPAPI) + "produsuaris/produsuari");
        httpDeleteWithBody.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpDeleteWithBody);
        Log.d("Response ---------->", response.getStatusLine().toString());
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.e("ServicioRest", "Error!", ex);
}
return resul;
```

Furthermore, I've tried to do this:

```
HttpDeleteWithBody delete = new HttpDeleteWithBody(getResources().getString(R.string.IPAPI) + "produsuaris/produsuari");
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(usuari.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);
se.setContentType("application/json");

delete.setEntity(se);
```

however, it doesn't work... the log says:

> D/Response ---------->﹕ HTTP/1.1 200 OK

This is how I call the method:

```
JSONObject deleteproduct = new JSONObject();
try {
    deleteproduct.put("idProducte", String.valueOf(IDPROD));
    deleteproduct.put("idusuari", String.valueOf(IDUSU));
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Log.i("Json test per afegir prod --> ", deleteproduct.toString());
TareaWSInsertar tarea = new TareaWSInsertar();
tarea.execute(String.valueOf(IDPROD), String.valueOf(IDUSU));
```

*I've added on my Google Chrome a plug-in called **"[PostMan](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm)"*** and when I try to do this by this way, it's deleting correctly...

[image: Figure 1]

What I'm doing wrong?

### EDIT

I tried to use `cURL`, and this is the result:

[image: Figure 2]

*It is returning me false, when I put the same `JSON` as `PostMan`; nevertheless, if I put the same `JSON` on `PostMan`, it works fine.*

### EDIT 2

I implemented [ion library](https://github.com/koush/ion) and I did it like :

```
 JSONObject usuari = new JSONObject();
            try {
                usuari.put("idProducte", params[0]);
                usuari.put("idusuari", params[1]);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                String url = getResources().getString(R.string.IPAPI) + "produsuaris/produsuari";
                Log.d("CURL", "curl -X DELETE -d '" + usuari.toString() + "' " + url);

                Builders.Any.F builder = Ion.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
                        .load(HttpDelete.METHOD_NAME, url)
                        .setTimeout(15000).setStringBody(usuari.toString());


                String response = builder.toString();
                Log.d("TEST", "Req response -->" + response);
            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                resul = false;
            }
```

And it still returning that it's OK, and don't delete anything.

Comment: Are you trying to delete something of your local db in your device, or are you trying to delete something from the database in the server side? Because if you are trying to delete something in the server side, I think that you are doing everything fine. Go and throw a punch in the back of the neck of the server side developer :P

Comment: I'm trying to delete soemthing from database in the server side not from SQLite

Comment: @astinx Why on PostMan works and on my Android App does not?

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't see that part, could you try to send the request through curl and see if that work or doesnt, then I can have an idea of why isn't working. It would be something like `curl -X DELETE -d '{json} http://web.service'` I think that this could be because a chunk error in the request, doing the request with curl will anser that question.

Comment: @astinx don't get you can you explain it with more details please?

Comment: if postman is correct - then this means the json you create that you post in the app is wrong

Comment: @Skizo Time ago I got the same exact issue. When I did try to make the request with curl, open a terminal in linux and executing the command `curl -X DELETE -d {json_raw_body} http://host.com/someWebService` returned: `curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining` this measn that is a chunk error, the server must have a `die()` or a `return` in some point of the code. If you don't use linux, you can download git and use the git console to execute it. I'm pretty sure that this is a server side error.

Comment: It does work on Postman and note with the HttpClient of java because Postman knows how handle it.

Comment: @astinx it returns false :S

Comment: @Skizo Did you try to do a request with any other webservice?. Try it, if the other ws works fine, then that means that something is wrong in the serverside, as I said, the programmer in the serverside must be doing something like `echo "{response_json}";` and after that a `die();` killing the response halfway. If you have any doubts, I'll leave you a snippet as answer where you can test the same request using Ion, I guarantee you that the request will fail. 100% that this is an server side issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem, what I've done is change the `HttpDelete` method on my `API`, and instead of send a `JSON`, I send parameters (like a `HttpGet`) and now my code is like :

```
   boolean resul = true;

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        String id____USER = params[0];
        String id____PROD = params[1];

        HttpDelete del =
                new HttpDelete(getResources().getString(R.string.IPAPI) + "produsuaris/produsuari?idProd=" + Integer.parseInt(id____PROD)+"&idUs="+Integer.parseInt(id____USER));

        del.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");

        try
        {
            HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(del);
            String respStr = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());

            if(!respStr.equals("true"))
                resul = false;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("ServicioRest","Error!", ex);
            resul = false;
        }

        return resul;
```

This is how I call this `AsyncMethod`

```
  TareaWSInsertar tarea = new TareaWSInsertar();
                                tarea.execute(String.valueOf(IDUSU),String.valueOf(IDPROD));
```

This work to me, I know it's not the best solution, but I've no much time, also I tried three solutions and noone didn't work.

Feel free to post a correct answer if you know what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a server side issue, to be sure of this, do the following:
1) Add Ion as an dependency in your grandle.

`compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:+'`

2) Use the following snippen to perform your request:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try{
        for(BasicNameValuePair aNameValue : getParameters()){

            jsonObject.put(aNameValue.getName(), aNameValue.getValue());
            Log.d("TEST","parameter "+aNameValue.getName()+": "+aNameValue.getValue());

        }
        jsonObject.put("time_zone", Util.timeZone());
        Log.d("TEST","parameter time_zone:"+Util.timeZone());
    }catch(Exception e){
        //
    }

    Log.d("CURL", "curl -X DELETE -d '"+jsonObject.toString()+"' "+getUrl());

    Builders.Any.F builder = Ion.with(getContext())
            .load(HttpDelete.METHOD_NAME, getUrl())
            .setTimeout(BuildConfig.HttpClientMaxTimeout).setStringBody(jsonObject.toString());

    String response = builder.asString().get();
    Util.checkThreadUiException();
    Log.d("TEST","-->"+ response);
```

There's no much rocket science, this is the code that I used in an app, in that method I received the parameters to send as a json, as a `BasicNameValuePair` collection. You can change that and directly set your json. I'm 100% porcent sure that this request will fail, because this is a server side issue.

**UPDATE**

```
JSONObject usuari = new JSONObject();
    try {
        usuari.put("idProducte", params[0]);
        usuari.put("idusuari", params[1]);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String url = getResources().getString(R.string.IPAPI) + "produsuaris/produsuari";
    Log.d("CURL", "curl -X DELETE -d '"+usuari.toString()+"' "+url);

    Builders.Any.F builder = Ion.with(getContext())
            .load(HttpDelete.METHOD_NAME, url)
            .setTimeout(BuildConfig.HttpClientMaxTimeout).setStringBody(usuari.toString());

    String response = builder.asString().get();
    Log.d("TEST","Req response -->"+ response)
```

**UPDATE**

Try this, perform this request through curl and let me know the result:

`curl  --http1.0 -X DELETE -d '{"idusuari":121,"idProducte":15}' 192.168.1.46/ServicioWebRest/api/produsuaris/produsuari`

Doing this you're telling to curl to send the request through http 1.0, chunked responses are only supported by http 1.1, if there's an error in the chunk encoding, this should tell you.

Also take a look to this [issue](https://github.com/koush/ion/issues/463#issuecomment-70241063) that I submitted to Ion long ago. I think that the problem that I was having that time, and your current problem are alike, maybe some of the tips there will help. Specially the part about the `addHeader("Connection", "close")`.

Would look like this:

```
 Builders.Any.F builder = Ion.with(getContext())
            .addHeader("Connection", "close")
            .load(HttpDelete.METHOD_NAME, getUrl())
            .setTimeout(BuildConfig.HttpClientMaxTimeout).setStringBody(jsonObject.toString());
```

Comment: Shall I add the `.addHeader("Connection", "close")`?

Comment: Yes I don't remember if the method's name is `header` or `addHeader` try both, should give you error if the method doesn't exist, though

Comment: Tried and nothing changes :l

Comment: The curl throw the same result even with the --http argument? Crap, Sorry I'm out of ideas then, I'll let you know if something new popups in my mind. Pretty sure that is something in the server side, though. By any change, the server side programmer is using Phalcon/CodeIgniter as framework?

Comment: yep it's the same Logcat :l it's made with c#

Comment: Shall I post the method of my C# API?

Comment: @Skizo Sure, maybe will help.

Comment: Thanks for waste your time trying to help me, but I had to do with other way (I posted the solution that I did). You helped me anyways :)